# How to print hashes using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the expected output something like this:

[image]

I don't seem to understand what's wrong with this code, it's accepting input other than 1 through 8, and also it's not printing out as expected.

I'm supposed to be printing an inverted pattern of hashes that forms a triangle but don't really know what went wrong.

here is the code

```
from cs50 import get_int

while True:
    n = get_int("Height: ")
    if n < 1 or n > 8:
        break

for i in range(n):
    for space in range(n-1):
        print(" ", end="")

        for j in range(i):
            print("#", end="")
            print()
```

I think there's something obviously wrong with the logic used

Comment: What happens if you enter 4? Does it do what you expect, or the opposite?

Comment: Double-check `if n < 1 or n > 8`.  You probably want to `break` the input loop on *valid* input, not *invalid* input.

Comment: you didn't say what code has to do. If it has to accept values between 1 and 8 then it has to be `if 1 <= n <= 8: break`

Comment: what about the printing of the inverted triangle being printed wrongly

Comment: @jarmod anytime i enter four it breaks, literally doing the opposite of what it's expected

Comment: @furas I already changed the if condition but still printing the wrong pattern

Comment: I still don't know what code has to do - I can't read in your mind. You have to show all details in question (not in comments). If you expect some pattern then show it in question. Show what value you enter and what outup it should display.

Comment: you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is douin. Or you would have to learn how to use real debuger. As for me you have wrong indentations - last `for`-loop shouldn't be inside second `for`-loop. And last `print()` may have also wrong indentation. And in Python indentations are very important and they can change everything.

Comment: It's doing exactly the opposite of what you want because your test is inverted. You should only break out of the while loop if the entered height is valid and that is when: `n >= 1 and n <= 8`.

Comment: @jarmod: The "pythonic" way to write that conditional is with `1 <= n <= 8` which @furas mentioned quite a while ago.

Comment: @jarmod I already edited that since, but I also pasted the link to the image screenshot of the expected output

Comment: @martineau agree, but suspect the OP may not appreciate/understand chained comparisons.  Also, was primarily replying to the OP's follow-up to my initial, somewhat pointed, question.

Comment: @furas I already added the picture to that post

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your expected output should be what happens if the user enters something not in the range of 1 to 8 — which you claim is the problem — not it working OK.

Answer (score 1):

You have few mistakes.

Two main problems are:

- you have to check `n >= 1 and n <= 8` or shorter `1 <= n <= 8`
- you have wrong indentations (and indentions are very important in Python).

This version

```
while True:
    n = int(input("Height: "))
    if 1 <= n <= 8:
        break

for i in range(n):

    # ---
    
    for space in range(n-1):
        print(" ", end="")

    # ---

    for j in range(i):
        print("#", end="")

    # ---
        
    print()
```

gives

```
Height: 5
    
    #
    ##
    ###
    ####
```

so it is almost good.

Now it needs different values in ranges:

- first range needs `range(1, n+1)` instead of `range(n)`
- second range needs variable `i` instead of value `1` - `range(n-i)`

```
while True:    
    n = int(input("Height: "))
    if 1 <= n <= 8:
        break

for i in range(1, n+1):
    
    # ---

    for space in range(n-i):
        print(" ", end="")

    # ---

    for j in range(i):
        print("#", end="")

    # ---
        
    print()
```

And now it gives

```
Height: 5
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

Comment: thanks so much, it worked, i really appreciated your effort helping me figure out the problem